# What's the differenet between three zkclient libraries on maven central repo

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper

New to zookeeper, and I was told to use zkclient library rather than the one offered by Apache. However, I find that there are [3 different flavors of zkclient on maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22zkclient%22):

- com.101tec
- com.github.adyliu
- com.github.sgroschupf

Which is right one to use?

Comment: see https://github.com/adyliu/zkclient for the last 2

Comment: Can't you just ask the person who told you to use this library?

Comment: @Roman, nobody tells me, I got the three by web search on maven central repo

Comment: Official Apache Kafka is using com.101tec https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ListTopicCommand.scala

Comment: Apache Kafka no longer uses 101tec in their latest versions https://github.com/mguenther/kafka-junit/issues/40